# Ways to use grep inside if statement with && operator?

Tags: bash

```
for i in $( seq 1 $maxTry )
do
  npm publish $package
  
  if grep -q "npm ERR!" # if there are any NPM errors
  then
     if [ [grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log"] && [ ! $i -eq $maxTry ] ];
     then 
        continue
     else
        break
   fi
```

I would like to retry the for-loop for $maxTry-amount of time only if:

1. the NPM Error is caused by the network error
2. the amount of retry time has not exceeded the $maxTry

Otherwise, it will break the loop. For example,

1. There is a NPM error, but not caused by the network error
2. Although it is a network error, it has reached the end of the loop

I am keep having a syntax error in `if [ [grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log"] && [ ! $i -eq $maxTry ] ]`. I am confused whether it is okay to put `grep -q` inside the if statement's bracket. Is this the right syntax?

Comment: No, `if grep ...` is the right syntax, already used in the fist if. But the first grep is missing a file.

Comment: The `[` isn't a property of `if`, it isn't part of the syntax. It is a command which is used to check file types and compare values.

Comment: In addition to the problems with `[ ]`, I think you're also confused about how `grep` works. You need to provide it with something to search, either by filename (`grep pattern fileToSearch`), or via standard input (`grep pattern <fileToSearch` or `commandThatPrintsOutput | grep pattern`). It looks like you're trying to search the output (maybe error output, which is separate?) from the `npm publish` command, in which case you need to capture that output somewhere so you can then search it.

Comment: If `npm publish` is well-behaved, you can use `if npm publish "$package"; then echo "publishing $package succeeded"; else echo "publishing $package failed"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` is not a structure operator. It is a command. Like grep is. Well, it is nowadays a built-in command, but yet, still a command. Back in the time, `[` was litteraly a command. A unix program. That you could find in `/usr/bin/[` (it is still there by the way. ls it on your PC. but not for bash, which has its own builtin `[`). In fact, it was then a link to `/usr/bin/test`. A command whose purpose is to test things.

It takes some arguments. Does some computation. And has an exit code 0 or 1, whether this computation decides it succeeds or not.

For example, you can try

```bash
$ /usr/bin/test a = b
$ echo $?
1
$ /usr/bin/test a = a
$ echo $?
0
$ /usr/bin/test -f .bashrc
0
$ /usr/bin/test -f anonexistingfile
1
```

One notable difference between `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` is that `/usr/bin/[` raises an error if the last argument is not `]`. Just of aesthetic reasons.

So, don't use `[` like a sort of parenthesis for grouping logic. Don't nest them. Don't use them to enclose other commands. It makes no sense.
Use `[` as you would use an external program, to which you pass arguments, and from which you expect an exit code.

Exactly like you to with `grep -q`.

`&&` is an operator separating two commands. Like `;` is. With a different behavior than `;`. `a && b` runs command a. And then runs command `b`, only if `a` exit code what 0. And the exit code of `a && b` is 0 iff exit code of both commands `a` and `b` where 0. Other wise it is the exit code of the first of them that failed.

And, lastly, `if` is used with a command.

```bash
if command0
then
    command1
else
    command2
```

Executes command0. And then executes command1 if command0 was successful (had an exit code 0), or command2 otherwise.

So, with that in mind, in your case, your line

```bash
if [ [grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log"] && [ ! $i -eq $maxTry ] ];
```

should be

```bash
if grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log" && [ ! $i -eq $maxTry ] ;
then
...
```

All my historical introduction shows you that it is just the same as

```bash
if grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log" && test ! $i -eq $maxTry  ;
then
...
```

It Executes command `grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log"`

- if it fails (exit code non-zero), then does not execute `[ ! $i -eq $maxTry ]`. And the whole if "condition" fails, and the `else` part is executed
- if it succeeds (exit code 0), executes command `[ ! $i -eq $maxTry ]`

  - if it fails, the whole if "condition" fails, and the `else` part is executed
  - if it succeeds, the whole if "condition" is a success, and the `then` part is executed.

Of course, the choice of `[` for that command name, and the choice of requiring that it terminates by a `]` is to makes it look a little bit like classical condition in other languages. But to understand this correctly, and not to struggle about when to add some `[`, it is important that you understand what `if`, what `&&` and what `[` mean in bash. `if` and `&&` are deciding if and when to execute several commands, and what exit code the group of several commands has. `[` aka `test` is just one of the many command you may want to execute. A command that does nothing, except having an exit code.

Last remark: I don't comment on the rest of your code. Only on the line about which was your question. For example,

```bash
grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log"
```

that I copied&pasted from your code to mine, because you gave no hint about what it is supposed to do.
But I have some doubt that this is what you want. Isn't there a missing dot between publish and log here?

The `-q` is right. It mean that grep will, like `[` a command that does nothing (prints nothing) and just have an exit code. So suited for usage in a if.
But then, you seems to be looking for a string "code ENOTFOUND" in a file named "publish log".

Likewise, I am pretty sure

```bash
if grep -q "npm ERR!"
```

is not what you wanted. It waits for lines on standard input, and succeeds (has exit code 0) if one of them contains "npm ERR!". I am pretty sure you intended to grep the content of a file. Like maybe the same `publish.log` as earlier.

And more generally I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. But I have the feeling that you are just trying to npm publish something over and over, until either it succeeds or you reach a maximum trial.
In which case

```bash
for ((i=0; i<$maxTry; i++))
do
   npm publish $package
   grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" publish.log || break
done
```

probably does it.

Maybe npm also has an exit code (well, it sure has. I just don't know whether it works for you. It returns 0 on success and non-0 on failure), and you could just do

```bash
for ((i=0; i<$maxTry; i++))
do
   if npm publish $package
   then
      break
   fi
done
```

or

```bash
for ((i=0; i<$maxTry; i++)); do
   npm publish $package && break
done
```

tl;dr (but if you don't want to always struggle with that kind of thing, that tl;dr won't cut it. It is giving a fish instead of teaching fishing): correct syntax is

```bash
if grep -q "code ENOTFOUND" "publish log" && [ ! $i -eq $maxTry ] ;
```